# Android - How to display HTML or RTF inside a Dialog

Tags: android, html

I have an Android app currently displaying some Terms of Service text inside a Dialog, from a .txt file

The issue is it is untidy and I would like to have a nicely formatted TOS and Welcome dialog.

How would I display either an HTML file (preferably) or RTF file in a dialog.

Current code ;

```
public abstract class CollectPage extends AppPage {
    final static int BUTTON_TERMS_AGREE = 0x20000;
    final static int BUTTON_TERMS_DECLINE = 0x20001;

    protected CollectPage(int nLayoutId) {
        super(nLayoutId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        enableLocation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onButtonClick(int nButtonId) {
        switch (nButtonId) {
            case BUTTON_TERMS_AGREE:
                WebService.acceptTOS(DataManager.getInstance().getAccountInfo().getId(), new NetTask.IObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void notifyData(byte[] arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleResult(byte[] arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                    }
                });
                if (mPendingTOSAggreement != null) {
                    mPendingTOSAggreement.run();
                    mPendingTOSAggreement = null;
                }
                break;
            case BUTTON_TERMS_DECLINE:
                exitApp();
                break;
            default:
                super.onButtonClick(nButtonId);
        }
    }
}
```

and ...

```
                    makeDialog("Terms Of Services", Utils.loadAssetTextAsString(getContext(), "terms.txt"), CollectPage.BUTTON_TERMS_AGREE,
                        getString(R.string.agree), CollectPage.BUTTON_TERMS_DECLINE, getString(R.string.decline));
                return;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Html.fromHtml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) to format text as HTML:

```
Html.fromHtml(Utils.loadAssetTextAsString(getContext(), "terms.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Html.fromHtml((String) htmlCode).toString();
```

to format the string you read from assets.